# ConstrainLayout: How to constrain a View's top to the bottom of the view of largest height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am currently trying `ConstraintLayout` in our project.

The layout I would like to implement can be simplified as following:

There are two views (say TopA and TopB) on the top of the layout, and there is another view (say BottomC) positioned below them.

TopB have changeable height, in different situations TopB's height may be larger or smaller than TopA's.

My questions is: how to constrain BottomC to the bottom of the Top view who has a larger height, so that BottomC won't be overlapped by the view with a larger height. (Screenshot attached below)

I can do that by adding TopA and TopB to an extra `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout` for example) and constrain BottomC to the bottom of that `ViewGroup`. But **is it possible to achieve that without introducing an extra layer of `ViewGroup`**?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your progress bar seems temporary which means it is to be enabled when loading or something. If that's the case then declare it below/after topViews as in ConstraintLayout unlike other layouts last declared widget remains on top. This way when Progress bar is enabled, it will remain on top with no effect of topView's size.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar The screenshots are just demos trying to make my question a bit clearer. `ProgressBar` can be any type of views. Thank you for the great suggestion though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

3 minutes after posting the question, I just found that recently released version 1.1.x of `ConstrainLayout` has a new feature called `Barrier`, and the official training doc of `ConstrainLayout` has been updated [to introduce it](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constrain-to-a-barrier).

This is exactly what I was looking for. Hope this can help guys like me.

The actual layout code looks like this (notice the `android.support.constraint.Barrier` node):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="Text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/topA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topA"
        />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="topA,topB"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/barrier4"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Ah!!! that's the name I was forgetting. This will be a great help for him.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this one is the common problem with the ConstraintLayout so basically there are two options, one is that if your imageview is of fixed height then set TextView minheight as imageview's height else ConstraintLayout is now introduced Barrier but this is in the Beta version if you want to use it with beta version set up as follow

**This is new feature introduced in ConstraintLayout which is currently in Beta version.**

How to add beta ConstraintLayout to project follow steps below

**add maven support in project gradle file as below**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**then in app gardle dependencies add ConstarintLayout library dependency**

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta3'
```

add barrier in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/barrier1"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView2, imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Now Beta3 is released with some fixes and new features**
https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/constraintlayout-110-beta-3-is-now.html

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
I recommend to do the following by adding the two views(Image, TextView) to a viewgroup(Any can do) then constraint the progressbar to the bottom of the viewgroup.(Edit:Just read the part were you said no view group so option 2)

Option 2:
But if u have to do it programmatically for animation or other reasons i recommend reading about:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html

and

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/TransitionManager.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just found that google has added a new feature called `Barrier` to `ConstrainLayout` in version 1.1.x, which solves the problem.

Comment: Actually, it's discouraged to nest views inside ConstraintLayout. The main goal of ConstraintLayout is to flatten layout. Read more [Understanding the performance benefits of ConstraintLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html)